# Definining the "$a \text{ mod } b$" operation to return b instead of 0.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can I redefine the modulo operation over integers $a \text{ mod } b$ to return $b$ instead of $0$? Example: $7 \text{ mod } 3= 1$ but $6 \text{ mod } 3=3$.

Comment: What do you mean by 'redefine'? By definition of modulo, $b \equiv 0$.

Comment: You could simply map (a,b) to b. Do you really need mod operator to achieve, what you intend to ?

Comment: Thank you. I mean, I need to define a function that behaves as described. I was wondering if this function had a name or could just be defined in terms of the mod operator. I could also simply define a new operator " mod' " which gives $b$ whenever the standard mod gives 0.

Comment: It's all down to what candidates you want to choose for the output of the $\mod x$ function. Some people choose  $\{1,2,...,x\}$ like you, and some choose $\{0,...,x-1\}$. It is a matter of choice, and you can make this switch without worrying, since the output of $\mod x$ is not a number, but rather an *equivalence class* of numbers, and all you are doing is choosing the representatives. In short, *the "standard" mod and the "redefined" mod are the same : there is no need for redefinition, and the statement $6 \mod 3 = 0$ is a correct statement*.

Answer (score 3):

Render the function as $1+(a-1)\bmod b$.  Done.